# How to do a NOT EXISTS for a value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm pretty clear on how to use `$exists` for a key in a document, but how I would go about doing it for a specific value of a key?

I have a User collection and a Log collection. I need to find, for all possible Users, the ones who don't have a specific value in a key, for a period of time.

Example: I want all Users that doesn't have Logging documents with the key-valye pair `"action":"login"`.

I thought about doing it like this, first I put all userIDs in an array:

```
var allUsers = [];
db.Usuario.find({},{_id:0,terminal:1}).forEach(function(d){allUsers.push(d.terminal)});
```

But I'm confused about how I would build the NOT EXISTS step of this operation.
Also, is there a more efficient way of achieving the above users array?

What I have so far:

```
db.Logging.find({
    /* what do I put in here? */,
    "terminal": { $in: allUsers },
    "timestamp": { $gte: dateToTimestamp('2017-12-06') }
})
```

Comment: That doesn't sound too complicated. However, you will need to post some sample data to get a proper answer.

Answer (score -1):

**$exist** - is use whether this key is present in the particular document or not.

**[$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** - is for the search the things in array and it is internally using the OR condition.

**[$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)** - I think this is the thing which you are looking for, this is use for get the documents which are not present in the array

Eg- db.inventory.find( { qty: { $nin: [ 5, 15 ] } } )db.inventory.find( { qty: { $nin: [ 5, 15 ] } } )`enter code here`

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't answer the question at all.